Can't Pull Array of Strings from Cloud Firestore and Put Them in a List
I'm trying to pull data from a cloud firestore database using a StreamBuilder and assign it to a List in Flutter.  The code below gives the error:

_TypeError (type '({bool growable}) => List' is not a subtype of type 'List')

    return ListView(
      children: snapshot.data!.docs
          .map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
            Map<String, dynamic> data =
                document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
                List<dynamic> listUsers = data['usersLiked'].toList;

usersLiked is an array of strings in the database.
I reviewed similar questions in stackoverflow but they don't seem to be the same and I haven't been able to modify this code so that I can just pull the data from the firestore database and put it into the list.  Any help would be appreciated.

toList is a function, so you need to invoke it by adding () after it: List<dynamic> listUsers = data['usersLiked'].toList(); --- Voting to close as a typo.

toList is a function, so you need to invoke it by adding () after it
List<dynamic> listUsers = data['usersLiked'].toList();


It worked.  Thanks!

I fixed it by iterating through the array in cloud firestore and adding each item to my list.  Here's the code:
List<String> listUsers = [];
   for (int i = 0; i < data['usersLiked'].length; i++) {
   listUsers.add(data['usersLiked'][i]);
   }

It seems there is probably an easier way to pull it, but I tried cast, toList and many other methods.  Just got different errors.
